# QGIS 3.22 Georeferencer Coordinate Reference System Selector not showing

Tags: qgis, raster, georeferencing

I'm using QGIS 3.22 trying to go through the 3.16 training manual - [14 Module: Forestry Application](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/training_manual/forestry/map_georeferencing.html) - When following the manual instructions after opening the Georeferencer and loading the raster, instead of showing the "Coordinate Reference System Selector" I got an error message `CRS was undefined: defaulting to project CRS EPSG:3067 - ETRS89 / TM35FIN(E,N)`.

After reviewing the literature I could not find the "options" tab where to check the "show CRS"

Comment: can you add a screenshot of the missing option you are looking for? and the step where you cannot move ahead with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally could figure it out. The design of the raster georeferencer in QGIS 3.22.1 has been changed. Now, after loading the source raster the plugin does not load the "Coordinate Reference System Selector" any longer. Instead when entering the first point the new form has a field for the CRS and once set it is use as entering further points.

[image: Map Coordinates Form]

Answer (score 2):

The look of the georeferencer may have changed since the tutorial was written. No automatic prompting happens but user must load the image and open the raster settings

[image]

Press the globe icon and select the coordinate reference system

[image]